# "CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding" in SSH session from Windows to macOs

Tags: ssh, windows-11, utf-8, macos-monterey

I need to run `pod install` on macOS 12.4 through ssh remotely from a Windows 11 machine.

To do this, I `ssh` into the macOS machine through `cmd`. However, when I run `pod install` in the secure shell, I get a warning message

```
WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

[image]

After this message, cocoapods tries to execute the install command, but fails.

I have verified that running pod install when logged into the GUI of the mac completes successfully.

**How can I successfully run `pod install` on the mac machine via a windows `ssh` session?**

---

**Things I've tried**

- Adding `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` to ~/.profile
- Switching the character encoding of my windows machine using what was
  suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/2011985) to a similar question. However, I still
  got the same error message.
- Running ssh and cocoapod through [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal), but
  this also gives the same error.

Comment: what results of `env`, when connected to ssh? To WHICH ~/profile are you adding that line?? While connected to ssh, type the `export LANG....` directly to the console, then try and run your pod...

Comment: Well, that was stupid of me. Running export `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` in the ssh did the trick. If you want to make an answer out of it, I'll mark it as accepted :)

Comment: I don't get paid for this, so not fussed ;) for the sake of permanence you need to add it to the ~/.profile on the mac, ie, the user you ssh -in- to. not your windows user's (omg is that even a thing, is windows heading toward posix compliance?!). Generally in *nix (which mac/darwin is) the location is `~/` (user's home directory)... `.bash_profile` which should be read by ANY shell/emulator, however pretty much everything nowdays ships with `sh` or `bash`... you'll obviously have to check/verify on the target system.

Comment: I had already tried adding it to the ~/.profile of the user, but somehow that still didn't work when logging in through ssh.